# Sanitizing comments or escaping comment_text()

Tags: comments, security, sanitization, escaping, input

I'm creating a template for comments on my WordPress site. I noticed that a simple `<script>alert(1);</script>` slips through the default WP codex implementation of comments, using the `comment_text()` function to display my comments. **No bueno**.

How can i properly sanitize and/or escape WordPress comments? The `esc_html()` function, seems to do nothing in this case.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't because you tested this as an administrator with the `unfiltered_html` capability?

Comment: @TomJNowell You are 100% right. I did not know, that this capability extended to comments as well, but I guess that this makes sense after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>After thinking about this a little bit, I guess that the proper way to ensure that your comments are properly escaped, is by doing something like this:</s>

```
$the_comment = get_comment_text();
echo '<p>' . esc_html($the_comment) . '</p>';
```

Instead of simply using the function like this:

```
comment_text();
```

Why even have these handy functions in the first place, if they aren't properly escaped? The `comment_author();` function IS, yet this is not for some reason?

Perhaps I am missing something?

I **was** missing something: the `unfiltered_html` capability given to the admin role, extends to comments. Read more here: https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#unfiltered_html